# ring destroy function not called on ./bin/jetty.sh stop?

Tags: clojure, ring

I have a ring project with the following configuration

```
:ring {:port 3000
       :handler myservice.core/standalone-app
       :init myservice.core/init!
       :destroy myservice.core/destroy!}
```

These functions are simple, they just log.  They may do more someday.

```
(defn init! [] (log/info "init!"))

(defn destroy! [] (log/info "destroy!"))
```

I build this kid with the uberwar thing.  `lein ring uberwar myservice.war`

The jetty log shows the init! logging on startup, but the destroy! logging is nowhere to be seen.  Is destroy even being called?  How can I tell?

The full project is at https://github.com/robertkuhar/myservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to configure the logging framework.  It seems strange in the absence of logging configuration allows init! to log to stdout, but destroy! goes nowhere.

I added logback to my project.clj as a dependency and gin'ed up a skeleton logback.xml config file and, viola!

```
2015-12-23 11:42:53.192:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.16.v20140903
2015-12-23 11:42:53.208:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /Users/robert.kuhar/work/jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/webapps at interval 1
...
2015-12-23 11:42:53.598:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /Users/robert.kuhar/work/jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/webapps/myservice.war
2015-12-23 11:42:53.600:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/Users/robert.kuhar/work/jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/webapps/myservice.war!/ to /private/var/folders/1g/fnytl2x93sx6hp2f1rsf4h1r5xtqv_/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myservice.war-_myservice-any-/webapp
2015-12-23T11:42:58.851 INFO m.core - app
2015-12-23T11:42:58.856 INFO m.core - standalone-app
println init!
2015-12-23T11:42:58.857 INFO m.core - init!
...
2015-12-23 11:42:59.146:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
...
2015-12-23 11:45:48.432:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
...
2015-12-23 11:45:48.434:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/myservice,file:/private/var/folders/1g/fnytl2x93sx6hp2f1rsf4h1r5xtqv_/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myservice.war-_myservice-any-/webapp/},/Users/robert.kuhar/work/jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/webapps/myservice.war
println destroy!
2015-12-23T11:45:49.553 INFO m.core - destroy!
...
2015-12-23 11:45:49.553:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/myservice,file:/private/var/folders/1g/fnytl2x93sx6hp2f1rsf4h1r5xtqv_/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myservice.war-_myservice-any-/webapp/},/Users/robert.kuhar/work/jetty-distribution-8.1.16.v20140903/webapps/myservice.war
...
```